# How can I compile the x10 example?

Tags: linux, x10-language

I'm currently reading [this](http://x10.sourceforge.net/documentation/guide/2.1.0/pguide.pdf) and I try to compile the very first example

```
// file HelloWorld.x10
public class HelloWorld {
    public static def main(args: Array[String](1)){
        x10.io.Console.OUT.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

I have Linux Mint 16. I set `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/`.
I've downloaded the "Linux/x86_64 (tgz)" version from http://x10-lang.org/x10-development/building-x10-from-source.html?id=248

I've tried to compile it like this:

```
$ ./x10 HelloWorld.x10       
Error: Cannot load main class for HelloWorld.x10 with classpath .:/home/moose/Downloads/x10-2.4.2_linux_x86_64/stdlib/x10.jar:/home/moose/Downloads/x10-2.4.2_linux_x86_64/lib/commons-math3-3.2.jar:/home/moose/Downloads/x10-2.4.2_linux_x86_64/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
```

and this:

```
./x10c HelloWorld.x10
/home/moose/Downloads/x10-2.4.2_linux_x86_64/bin/HelloWorld.x10:3: Could not find type "Array(x10.lang.Long)".
1 error.
```

and this

```
./x10c++ HelloWorld.x10
/home/moose/Downloads/x10-2.4.2_linux_x86_64/bin/HelloWorld.x10:3: Could not find type "Array(x10.lang.Long)".
1 error.
```

and this:

```
./runx10 HelloWorld.x10
/home/moose/Downloads/x10-2.4.2_linux_x86_64/bin/HelloWorld.x10: line 1: //: Is a directory
/home/moose/Downloads/x10-2.4.2_linux_x86_64/bin/HelloWorld.x10: line 2: public: command not found
/home/moose/Downloads/x10-2.4.2_linux_x86_64/bin/HelloWorld.x10: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/moose/Downloads/x10-2.4.2_linux_x86_64/bin/HelloWorld.x10: line 3: `    public static def main(args: Array[String](1)){'
```

How should I run / execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the main method has changed between version 2.1 (on which the introduction you're reading was based) and version 2.4.  The correct signature is:

```
public static def main(args:Rail[String])
```

A current version of "Hello World" (along with other examples) is included in the X10 distribution in `x10.dist/samples` .  A more up-to-date introduction to X10 is available at http://x10.sourceforge.net/documentation/intro/latest/html/

Comment: Now I get `Public type must be declared in .x10 file.`

Comment: That usually means the class name doesn't match the file name - could you please check whether that's the case?

Comment: Yes, it was the case. Thank you!